# SAS view permanent inputs/outputs of a project or program

Tags: sas

Is there any way to view all permanently stored datasets used by or created by a SAS project (or program, if this is not possible)? I have been tasked with creating a matrix of data inputs and outputs for 40 different SAS projects, each of which contains at least 50 programs. Needless to say there are THOUSANDS of temporary datasets created, but all I am interested in are the permanent ones. After manually checking one project, I noticed that the project process flow does not contain many permanently stored inputs (i.e. from libraries other than WORK) and it is very time consuming to check the properties of each dataset to see if it is temporary or not.

Three other things of note-
1. None of the code is documented.
2. I did not write any of it.
3. I am using SAS enterprise guide

Comment: SAS notation is pretty distinct for permanent data sets. Are the libnames going to be standard or can each user create their own? You can export each project to a SAS program and then parse the programs looking for LIBNAME.MEMNAME pattern via prx. It's a bit easier if you're looking for specific library names.  Anyways, this is a very broad open question and you'd need to provide more details. Also, look at PROC SCAPROC, but for this to work you have to run the programs. Search lexjansen.com for code analyzer macros, or write your own. I would consider documenting the programs while doing this

Answer (score 0):

it is not exactly clear what you are asking for.  You may want to check out the table sashelp.Vcolumn which will contain a list of all permanent data sets and lists variables of each table.  If your project stored all data sets in one library you could try:

```
proc sql;
select * from sashelp.vcolumn
where libname ="yourprojectslibrary";
```